# Why the process is not terminated?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to multithreading. While reading 'Programming Python' by Mark Lutz I stuck at this line

> note that because of its simple-minded infinite loops, at least one of
>   its threads may not die on a Ctrl-C on Windows you may need to use
>   Task Manager to kill the python.exe process running this script or
>   close this window to exit

But according to my little knowledge about threading 
all thread terminate when main thread exits. So why not in this code?

```
# anonymous pipes and threads, not process; this version works on Windows


import os
import time
import threading


def child(pipe_out):
    try:
        zzz = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(zzz)
            msg = ('Spam %03d\n' % zzz).encode()
            os.write(pipe_out, msg)
            zzz = (zzz + 1) % 5
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Child exiting")


def parent(pipe_in):
    try:
        while True:
            line = os.read(pipe_in, 32)
            print('Parent %d got [%s] at %s' % (os.getpid(), line, time.time()))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Parent Exiting')


pipe_in, pipe_out = os.pipe()
threading.Thread(target=child, args=(pipe_out, )).start()
parent(pipe_in)
print("main thread exiting")
```

Comment: "all thread terminate when main thread exits" Where did you get this assumption from?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: No I was asking if you have built your assumption on something you read, but it might be the answer to your question, they do not.

Answer (score 1):

A Python process will end when there are no more running **non-daemon** threads. If you pass the `daemon=True` argument to `threading.Thread` you will notice different behavior in your program.

I suggest reading the docs for the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module to learn more about what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally understand.